# Mock doesn't work, while reassignment does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I have the following Jest/Enzyme test:

```
 const mockCheckMyFunctionality = jest.fn();
 jest.mock('../modules/MyFunctionality', () => ({
    checkMyFunctionality: mockCheckMyFunctionality
 }));
 const wrapper = shallow(
    <App initialProps={mockInitialProps} />
 );
 expect(mockCheckMyFunctionality).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

This will fail with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNextTick' of undefined`. The error message itself is not relevant, but it just shows that the real `MyFunctionality.checkMyFunctionality` is called instead of `mockCheckMyFunctionality`.

However, if I replace:

```
 jest.mock('../modules/MyFunctionality', () => ({
    checkMyFunctionality: mockCheckMyFunctionality
 }));
```

With:

```
 MyFunctionality.checkMyFunctionality = mockCheckMyFunctionality;
```

The test will pass, showing that `mockCheckMyFunctionality` is actually called. However, this is hacky and fails EsLint checking.

The method I am testing is just this:

```
setupMyFunctionality() {
    checkMyFunctionality(this.props.something);
}
```

How can I modify the mocking such that it is visible inside `App`?

Reassignment seems to work but mocking doesn't.

Comment: maybe an issue with async `jest.mock()`? by the time you create `wrapper`, the callback has not yet run.

Comment: I don't think so. I called a sleep function with 8 seconds after calling `jest.mock` and the test still fails. Interesting suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to create a manual mock for the `MyFuncionality` module.
As in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) for mocking a module:

> Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a `__mocks__/`
>   subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. For example, to mock a module called `user` in the `models` directory, create a file called `user.js` and put it in the `models/__mocks__` directory.
>   ...
>   When a manual mock exists for a given module, Jest's module system will use that module when explicitly calling `jest.mock('moduleName')`.

If that's the case, you can create a folder named `__mocks__` adjacent to the `MyFunctionality` file, then create a `MyFunctionality` file within that folder, containing the mock implementation as in the code snippet, and explicitly call the mock by calling `jest.mock('../modules/MyFunctionality')` before the tests.

Another solution, which I started using in my projects, is passing the dependencies as props to the components. To implement that you could change the `App` component and pass the `MyFunctionality` as props, thus in the above test you would need just to pass the mock implemented as props, avoiding the necessity of creating `__mocks__/` folder to accomplish the test.